# android studio new layouts getting created in debug folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio. New activites and layout files are getting created in `debug/src` folder instead of `main/src`. Some files are in debug folder. Please help?

[image: See screenshot of folders]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a new layout resource file set **Source set:** to main instead of debug.

Comment: There is no source option in new android studio while creating new activity.